# How can I prepare for a short circuit between 5V and GND pins?

Tags: safety, fuses

My Arduino Uno controls a couple of LEDs in a watertight enclosure. I'm running wires from ground, a data pin, and the 5 V pin into the enclosure. The Arduino is powered through the DC jack.

What measures can I take to handle failure of the watertight enclosure, which would short-circuit the wires? Can I protect the Arduino, or at least prevent a fire?

Comment: simply put a fuse inline with the power jack, say 1 amp (if the LEDs aren't powerful). Also, water won't cause a dead-short, and with only 5v, you don't really have to worry about a fire, unless you're doing something weird you didn't mention.

Comment: Nothing weird! Thank you. Do you mean to put the fuse right after the 5V pin? What would be an appropriate fuse for this?

Comment: Se this WONDERFULL [vid](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pGLUsQozT94)  (is just 8 mins!!!)

Comment: they make pre-assembled DC inline fuses ([like these](https://www.ebay.com/itm/121479236378)) if you don't want to solder in a fuse holder. The fuse should be sized as 1.5-2X your expected load in amps.

Comment: @k.Cyborg Thank you, seems I hade several misconception about water.

Comment: @dandavis Thanks a lot! Can I just ask, what is the reason to put the fuse between the power supply and Arduino, as opposed to between the Arduino and the potential short?

Comment: well you can do both; i'm evidently not sure of your exact setup, i thought everything was in the enclosure, so putting it up-front made sense in terms of preventing a fire. The MCU should not be in a position to blow out if shorted; GPIOs can be pulled to ground or VCC without issue...

Comment: What are you using to supply power to the DC jack? The problem with a fuse could be that the power supply can’t provide enough current to blow the fuse, making it useless.

Answer (score 0):

Shoutout to @k.Cyborg who gave a very nice pointer in the comments to a YouTube video on the effects of water on electronics!

One of the things you can do to handle failure of the watertight enclosure better is to use nail polish clear coat and apply that over your board - it will form a protective layer. I use this technique on protoboards with solder bridges on the bottom - adding a layer of clear coat seals them and prevents any shorts due to placing the bottom of the board on a conductive surface, or from fingers touching and shorting things. This would work with water too, to prevent any electrolytic reaction and corrosion, which the video talks about. The video also briefly shows a nail polish clear coat (but doesn't elaborate and says it's a topic for another video).

Another point to consider when talking about shorts. In my case, I was powering my Arduino Pro Mini through the Vin , connected to a 9v battery. I fried the LDO on it by briefly reversing the polarity by switching the terminals by mistake (nice puff of magic smoke!). I added a reverse polarity protection diode in series with the + to prevent a repeat on my next Pro Mini. Since you are powering your Uno through the DC jack (which has a reverse polarity protection diode), it is not an issue for you, but thought I'd mention it if you plan to move to Vin.